# While importing A comma-separated values (CSV) file on company server error showing invalid file format

Tags: c#

While importing A comma-separated values (CSV) file on company server error showing invalid file format  But when I have tried locally or from testing server the same file is importing

Comment: You will need to add more information than this to get a reliable answer, however I'm going to take a guess and ask the following.  Is the system language on the server and local computer different?

Answer (score 0):

Check default Windows CodePage both on server and local computer.